# Using PIL to draw individual pixels, but the image is blurry

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to create an image made up of coloured squares. I only need each square to be one pixel large, as it is just a single block colour. However, when I use this code, the image generated is extremely blurry. Is there anyway to make the boarders sharp?

```
def fancycolnw2(seq,m):
    data=numbwall(seq,m)
    #print(data)
    for i in range(len(data)):
        for j in range(len(data[i])):
            if data[i][j]==' ':
                data[i][j]=-1
    im = Image.new('RGBA', (len(data[0]),len(data))) # create the Image of size 1 pixel 
    #print(data)
    for i in range(len(data)-1):
        for j in range(len(data[i])-1):    
            #print(i,j)
            if data[i][j]==-1:
                im.putpixel((j,i), ImageColor.getcolor('black', 'RGBA'))
            if data[i][j]==0:
                #print('howdy')
                im.putpixel((j,i), ImageColor.getcolor('red', 'RGBA'))
            if data[i][j]==1:
                im.putpixel((j,i), ImageColor.getcolor('blue', 'RGBA'))
            if data[i][j]==2:
                im.putpixel((j,i), ImageColor.getcolor('grey', 'RGBA'))
    im.show()
    im.save('simplePixel.png') # or any image format
```

The result I get looks like this:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIZF9.png)

It is the correct image, I just wish the boundaries between pixels were sharp. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: When zooming in an image, the viewer uses interpolation to do so, which may blur it depending on which method is used. You could resize the image to solve this or change the interpolation

Comment: The "sharpness" of single pixels depends on your display (hardware), not on the code you write.

Answer (score 0):

The image is perfectly sharp, but rather small. I suspect that you are "zooming in" to view it clearer, and that whatever program you are zooming with is filtering the image, because with most images this looks better. You need to find a viewing program that uses "nearest neighbour" resampling when zooming in, or generate a larger image to start with, for example by setting a 4-by-4 pixel block rather than individual pixels.

(Also, the code says "# or any other image format". *Don’t* use JPEG for this, as the lossy compression will likely wreck your image.)

Comment: Thanks for explaining that! I have found a nearest neighbour viewing program and it is exactly like I wanted. Thanks again!